# How to track which DNS my computer is using

Tags: networking, dns

My ISP poison my DNS to block adult sites.

If I do

```
Pinging adultfriendfinder.com [202.73.99.3] with 32 byt
Reply from 202.73.99.3: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=61
Reply from 202.73.99.3: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=61
Reply from 202.73.99.3: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=61
Reply from 202.73.99.3: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=61

Ping statistics for 202.73.99.3:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 9ms, Maximum = 18ms, Average = 12ms

C:\Users\TOSHIBA>ping pornhub.com

Pinging pornhub.com [202.73.99.3] with 32 bytes of data
Reply from 202.73.99.3: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=61
Reply from 202.73.99.3: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=61
Reply from 202.73.99.3: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=61
Reply from 202.73.99.3: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=61
```

I already change DNS on the modem and on the computer and on the connection.

Somehow pinging all adult sites still lead to that same IP 202.73.99.3

I want to scan what's wrong.

It used to work. I used to be able to bypass this stupid blocking. Then suddenly I couldn't anymore for no reason.

I want to trace how my computer got the IP addresses. I do not think it's cached.

Comment: Check your hosts file and make sure there isn't a mention there to the wrong ip. the hosts file takes priority over everything, so even if you can't figure it out, you can put an entry there to make it work again regardless if something changes the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "NSLookup" tool - see [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200525) if you use Windows.
(I don't use Windows, but the process is the same regardless of OS, so the following should work):

Query your primary nameserver (ie the address in your DNS settings) by running 
nslookup 
server ip.of.server
pornhub.com

Should output the answer that server gets.

A more advanced version of the query it to trace the nameservers each nameserver relies on by looking up what it sees - for example

nslookup
server 8.8.8.8
set q=ns
pornhub.com

server sdns3.ultradns.net
pornhub.com
set q=A
pornhub.com

To trace the tree of DNS results.

Its sounds likely to me that your ISP is hijacking traffic on port 53, which means you would probably need to negotiate with them to stop doing that (they may have quietly opted you into a "child friendly" service you can opt out of), change ISP's or start using a VPN.